# Don't get expected error output with C program

Tags: c, linux, bash, sh

I have a little script called by a `cron` task that only launches a program and redirects the standard output in a file and the error output in an other. The problem is that it works well for standard output but not for error output.

Here my script:

```
#/bin/bash

echo "---------------------------------------------" \
     >> /usr/src/parser_mail/bin/log/log
echo "Parsing du " `date` >> /usr/src/parser_mail/bin/log/log
echo "---------------------------------------------" \
     >> /usr/src/parser_mail/bin/log/log
/usr/src/parser_mail/bin/parser \
     >> /usr/src/parser_mail/bin/log/log \
     2>> /usr/src/parser_mail/bin/log/error
```

After few test, it apear that my parser don't send any error...

The code :

```
if (mysql_query(conn, sql))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\n#################################################\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "ERREUR : %s\nInscription annulee pour cette horaire.\n",
        mysql_error(conn));
    fprintf(stderr, "#################################################\n");
}
else
{
    printf("*");fflush(stdout);
}
```

And I can see in log that the "*" is not printed. So There it should print some thing on error output.

Comment: Are you seeing the standard error showing up somewhere else? Or not showing up at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is get rid of the stuff we can't see in the question, which is your actual parser.

Change your command temporarily from:

```
/usr/src/parser_mail/bin/parser
```

to:

```
( echo xyzzy_output ; echo xyzzy_error >&2 )
```

and leave the redirections on the end. You should see the two lines go in to the two separate files.

---

If they do, then it's likely your parser isn't behaving itself, such as not sending anything to `stderr`, or conflating the two handles so they go to the same place *before* your redirections kick in.

In that case, you may want to run the parser from the command line with something like:

```
/usr/src/parser_mail/bin/parser >xyzzy_out 2>xyzzy_err
```

and see what shows up in each file. It may be that the parser is not *sending* anything to `stderr`, for example.

---

If you *don't* get both files with correct output, then you need to look at other possibilities like permissions, or mad processes running around deleting files without your knowledge :-)

Comment: Thank you, it helps ! So It works fine with that test... So I don't know why errors of parser are not reported...

Comment: @Emrys, see my penultimate paragraph. The parser may not be _sending_ anything to `stderr`, instead writing errors to `stdout`, for example. Or maybe there _are_ no errors. I'll update with some more info.

Comment: The is that I'm sure I have an error and I have made it send to stderr... I will update my question.

Comment: Ok I don't know why but it works now... Thank you for yout help